# Get Ip from TcpClient using f#

Tags: f#

Hi I have a question.

I am having simple server that looks like :

```
let private Listener ip port =
    async {

    let listener = new TcpListener(ip, port)
    listener.Start()   

    _logger.Info(printfn "Server binded to IP: %A - Port: %i" ip port)

    while listener.Pending() = false do

        try
            let! client = listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
            clientConnectionPool.Add(client) |> ignore 
            _logger.Info(printfn "Client connected: %O" client.Client.RemoteEndPoint)
        with
            | :? ServerListenerException as ex -> _logger.Error(printfn "Exception while starting server listener - %s" ex.Message); ()

    }
```

And well it works, problem is now I want to get client Ip addres, normally in c# i would use:

```
((IPEndPoint)entry.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address
```

And I believe in F# translate into:

```
let clientIp : IPAddress = (client.Client.RemoteEndPoint :> IPEndPoint).Address
```

But problem is I am getting message

> Type constraint mismatch. The type 'EndPoint' is not compatible with type 'IPEndPoint'

What could be the issue??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In F# upcast and downcast are two separate things. This makes sense: upcast never fails, never results in a `null`, never throws an exception. Downcast may fail. What if that `RemoteEndPoint` value turns out not to be an instance of `IPEndPoint`?

As such, upcast and downcast are represented by two different operators. The one you're using - `:>` - is upcast. It only works if the target type is a supertype of the source type. Which in your case it is not - that's what the error is telling you.

The downcast operator is `:?>`. Try this:

```
let clientIp : IPAddress = (client.Client.RemoteEndPoint :?> IPEndPoint).Address
```